# What is a candy or chocolate bar packaging informally called?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

Many a time I wanted to ask my daughter to pick up the "package" left on the ground after eating her Snickers.

How would you say so in everyday English?

Answer (score 14):

I'd call it the *wrapper* : see [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wrapper) but it basically means the packaging around something.

> Can you please pick up the wrapper?